# How to fix all tags and issues in Javadoc, excluding certain tags?

Tags: java, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am migrating old Ant projects to Maven. There are some issues with Javadoc for newer versions of Java, so I am fixing it by `mvn javadoc:fix`.

The issue that the plugin itself adds `author` and `version` tags. I want to exclude them. Maven Javadoc plugin [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html) doesn't give me a clue how to do it.

Is there any way to fix issues BUT exclude some of the tags? I also don't want to touch these tags if they already exist, so fix -> remove may not work.

I looked through the plugin docs, StackOverflow, and existing solutions. So far, no results.

[Github project](https://github.com/ChameleonTartu/amazon-mws-feeds-maven) I am running `mvn javadoc:fix` on.

Answer (score 0):

With [fixTags](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html#fixTags) you can specify which tags you want to fix.

```
mvn javadoc:fix -DfixTags=param,return,throws,link
```